# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (3, 32, 32) but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train  CNN for cifar10 datasets but got this error 
Error when checking input: expected conv2d_10_input to have shape (3, 32, 32) but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)

[this is my CNN model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubGa4.png)

epochs = 10
batch_size = 32

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose = 1)

Comment: change this 'input_shape=(32, 32, 3)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the dataset is in (Height, Width, CHannel) format but the model is expecting (Channel, Height, Width) format.

We can convert between these using the `tf.transpose()` function which can "switch" around the dimensions of a tensor.

TO convert a single image tensor from HWC to CHW just do:

```py
reshaped = tf.transpose(image_tensor, (2,0,1))
```

To convert a batch you can do:

```py
reshaped = tf.transpose(images_tensor, (0,3,1,2))
```

Comment: your you can set `channels_last = False`